# In ruby, how can I get the substring from a pattern to a pattern? Also, how do I get the last such pattern?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, grep, substring

Say I have the following string :

```
This is a test. This is a Test. The test_id = "miaomiao"
```

I simply want to return the "miaomaio"

Also, just to add : Say I have multiple ones :

```
"This is" a test. Thq3gis is a The test_id = "woofwoof"""""""""Test.qfqs 
This is "a testeqgq3. This" The test_id = "hisshiss"is a Test. 
This is a tfqefest. This "is a Test". eqgThe test_id = "moomoo"
This is a test. This is gqwa Test. qefThe test_id = "roarroar"
This is a test. This is a Tqqest. faqThe test_id = "miaomiao"
```

And once again I want to return "maiomiao" The whole thing in the latter case is a string containing spaces and returns.

Comment: use this http://rubular.com/r/LA3TSkUFWZ . Try the code `str = 'This is a test. This is a Test. The test_id = "woofwoof"'
str[/=\s+"(\w+)"$/,1] # => "woofwoof"`..

Comment: Have you tried to solve this? Can you post your code?

Comment: I'm very new to ruby. My idea was to read the whole thing into an array and then get a substring. I'm looking for a faster way.

Comment: Hmmm, it looks like you've got an issue with the data entry folks. Might want to have a chat with HR.

Comment: Or someone here hasn't ever done a grep through a server log.

Comment: Please post the code that is supposed to 'analyze' your data. Otherwise we will just keep guessing randomly.

Comment: In the end I did : ``grep 'test_id ' FILE | tail -1`.sub(/.*?= "/, '').partition('";')[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to extract whatever's inside double quotes:

```
>> test_string = 'This is a test. This is a Test. The test_id = "miaomiao"'
=> "This is a test. This is a Test. The test_id = \"miaomiao\""
>> test_string.scan /".+"/
=> ["\"miaomiao\""]
```

or

```
>> test_string[/".+"/]
=> "\"miaomiao\""
```

or, if you just want what's inside the quotes without the quotes,

```
>> test_string[/"(.+)"/,1]
=> "miaomiao"
```

for multiple matches you could use

```
>> test_string
=> "This is a test. This is a Test. The test_id = \"miaomiao\" This is a test. This is a Test. The test_id = \"waowao\""
>> test_string.scan(/".+?"/)
=> ["\"miaomiao\"", "\"waowao\""]
```

and for multiple matches that omit the quotes from the result, use a positive lookahead / lookbehind:

```
>> test_string.scan(/(?<=")(\w+?)(?=")/).flatten
=> ["miaomiao", "waowao"]
```